# Develop Google Chrome Apps in Visual Studio Tools for Cordova

Tags: google-chrome-app, visual-studio-cordova

I'd like to use Visual Studio Tools for Cordova to develop a Google Chrome App (https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps)

Is there any way to import a cca project into Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

I've not tried, but its not an officially supported workflow.

Since Chrome Apps for Mobile (cca) are based on cordova its probably not impossible.. but we do have some custom hooks, and we do some transformations inside the cca tool itself.  I would expect you could do most development from Visual Studio, but if you make changes to `manifest.json` / `manifest.mobile.json`, or want to build release versions, you will probably need to use the `cca` tool from the command like to `cca prepare`.

If you get it to work, do report back, I'm curious!

Comment: Conflicted: it's not a _very good_ answer, but it's as authoritative as it can get. Still, upvoted.